# Editing Meetings in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, meetings

my boss has recurring meetings on his calendars that take place off site. He wants me to change the start and end time of each meeting to allow for travel time.  Another person originally scheduled these meetings. I am able to change the start and end time but if the person who originally scheduled cancels or changes will my boss get the updates?

Comment: To those voting to close as the dupe @CharlieRB pointed out: "I am able to change the start and end time".  This is a different question than "how do I do it"; it's "What happens when..." :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Good catch. I was looking at it all wrong. Vote retracted.

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook 2013, I changed the time of a meeting request sent by someone else. This is the prompt you will receive:

[image]

This creates an exception to the recurring meeting and the changes are only local to you. If the meeting requestor updates the meeting, that will overwrite whatever local changes you have made. This assumes the meeting requester is also using Outlook.

[More details here](http://www.outlook-tips.net/tips/changing-date-recurring-appointment/).